# Unhandled promise rejection [Error: Cannot convert argument of type class [Ljava.lang.String;]

Tags: java, react-native, kotlin

I am making a React Native module and I am using kotlin for Android.
I have a method in my native module like so:

```
@ReactMethod
    fun blahblah(promise: Promise) {
      try {
        // This returns a Set<String> so I have to convert it to a typed array

        val data = myMethod.toTypedArray()
        promise.resolve(data)
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        promise.reject(e)
      }
    }
```

when I call it in my code I am getting this error:
 `Unhandled promise rejection [Error: Cannot convert argument of type class [Ljava.lang.String;]`

Is this a problem with bridge? Am I missing something? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Will it work if you change `catch (e: Exception)` with `catch (e: Throwable)`?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь no same result. :(

Answer (score 2):

For me resolve a `WritableArray` solve problem:

```
    @ReactMethod
fun blahblah(promise: Promise) {
    val array = Arguments.createArray()
    array.pushString("str1")
    array.pushString("str2")
    promise.resolve(array)
}
```